# Fetch is not working even though the URL is correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to use a simple fetch function for a JSON web token but it's not working even though the URL is correct. Here is the front end function:

```
 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/verify", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
        }).then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                console.log("bruh");
            }

            response = response.json();
            const token = response.token;
            if (token) {
                const json = jwt.decode(token);
                setMessage("Welcome admin with token of " + json.username);
                console.log(message);
            } else {
                setMessage("Something went wrong");
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("errrorrr:", error);
    }

    //router.push("../homePage/home");
};
```

here is the back end function:

```
 app.get("/api/verify", (req, res) => {
                console.log("function called");
                if (!req.body) {
                    res.statusCode = 404;
                    res.send("Error");
                    return;
                }

                const { email, password } = req.body;

                res.json({
                    token: jwt.sign(
                        {
                            username: email,
                            admin: email === "admin" && password === "admin",
                        },
                        KEY
                    ),
                });
            });
```

Everything seems okay. but I get this error:

```
signup.js:48     POST http://localhost:8080/api/verify 404 (Not Found)
```

Guys here is another example which works in my code:
backend:

```
app.get("/api/home", (req, res) => {
res.json({ message: "Server is Up!" });
   });
```

frontend:

```
                 useEffect(() => {
                    try {
                        fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/home")
                            .then((response) => {
                                if (!response.ok) {
                                    throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
                                }
                                return response.json();
                            })
                            .then((data) => {
                                console.log(data);
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.error("Errorsss:", error);
                            });
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log("error: ", error);
                    }
                }, []);
```

this example works perfectly well on both backend and frontend
I am also using nodemon which auto updates the server

Comment: still not working same error

Comment: i have updated the code please check

Comment: @MoeezMahmoodRamay: When you debug the server-side code, does `console.log("function called");` execute?  Is `if (!req.body)` true?

Comment: no the function called is not executed and if(!req.body) is true

Comment: @MoeezMahmoodRamay: ... How can that `console.log` statement not be executed, but you observe that the statement *immediately after it* is executed?  Additionally, if that condition is true then look at what's inside that condition.  The code explicitly returns a 404.  And you're getting a 404.  So, to clarify, you are confirming that your endpoint **is** being reached and that your logic is **explicitly** returning a 404?  That logic appears to be based on a request body, but a GET request has no body.  So it will *always* return a 404.

Comment: YESS, now the function is being called thank you. It worked after disabling cache. This was my first time with api's you didnt have to dislike the question :(

Comment: Yes, the evidence seems to be it's still attempting a GET.  "Clear Browser Data -> Cached images and files"

Comment: also if you could help me with this further error:
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'E', "Errorsss bruh" is not valid JSON
it is caused in backend when the first if condition fails i just changed the console.log("Error") to errorss bruh

Comment: Glad it's working.  Browsers are fun.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't you be defining "app.post" and not "app.get"?

```
app.post("/api/verify", (req, res) => {
```

Also for anyone finding this answer:
Notwithstanding the issue above, hidden in the comments, the OP also needed to disable their script caching via the browser development tools to prevent calling the old script.

Comment: its still not working

Comment: But still was a bug

Comment: yes but do you think there is anyother way?

Comment: Are you at least now seeing your log message, "function called"?

Comment: no the function is not being called